# Algorithms: Aggregate of substrings to determine relevant information

Tags: javascript, algorithm, aggregate, summarization

I am trying to do an aggregate algorithm that will get the most important elements in a text based on user highlights.

Imagine you have a text having n words where you have the ability to select k continuous words from the text as a "relevant highlight", where 1<=k<=n.(k is a substring of n)

Assuming we select anywhere from 10 to 10000 of these k highlights, is there any algorithm that can determine the most important information?

Consider that many of the highlights would overlap and we need to take that into account. I am also preferably looking for a solution in javascript since it's for a chrome extension.

This is NOT for a class, this is for a personal project concerning crowd-based summarization.

Comment: How would you decide what's important? Important to who?

Comment: important as in sentences that are chosen the most amount of times by the users selections @Dave Newton

Comment: What method is utilized to "highlight" text ? Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 for each highlight, we will get the information retrieving the text highlighted and a prefix and suffix of the match.

Comment: Does "highlight" contain more than one word ? If possible , can post sample of 10 "highlight"'s , and / or sample object or array containing "highlights" ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that each user highlights some stretches of text and that you know what those highlights are. You could sum, for each word in the text, how many people highlighted it. One thing you could calculate is, for some fixed k and N, a total of k stretches using at most N words in all, such the sum of the number of times those N words were highlighted was a maximum.

You can do this with dynamic programming, working left to right within the text. For each point in the text and each possible allowed combination of (# highlights, # total words highlighted, whether current word is highlighted) you work out the score for the best answer terminating at that point satisfying those constraints. You can work out the best answer at each point by using the best answers for the previous word - consider the possible scores you get if you take any one of the existing best answers and either extend a current highlight, if that last word was highlighted, or start a new highlight. At the end you track the best answer for the whole text back from right to left.

This gives you a summary in the form of the best section of k stretches to highlight, using at most N words to pick up as many of the words highlighted by users as possible. No doubt there are variations on this for different scores or for different highlighting constraints - it might be easier to compute the best combination of k stretches, where each stretch is of at most M characters.